# Plotly on Google Colab with axis and title error: "[object Object]"

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to use Plotly on Google Colab, so I generated random numbers and then tried to plot them on a Scatterplot. The problem was when I tried changing the `go.Layout`, because the **Title**, **X-Axis** and **Y-Axis** appear with the text `[object Object]` (image below).

I followed [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hJT54bhe03cQGurzmMCeJiyJBz5R7Njz) to come up with my code:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(84)

random_x = np.random.randint(1,101,100)
random_y = np.random.randint(1,101,100)

data = [go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y, mode='markers')]
lt = go.Layout(title="Random Plot",
                   yaxis={'title': 'Y-Axis'},
                   xaxis={'title': 'X-Axis'})

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=lt)
py.iplot(fig)
```

To set up Plotly on Colab I used the following code on a different cell (above the one with the actual plot configuration):

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

def configure_plotly_browser_state():
  import IPython
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
  <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  <script>
  requirejs.config({
    paths: {
      base: '/static/base',
      plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.5.1.min.js?noext',
      },
      });
  </script>
  '''))
```

Any clues?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's been awhile but if you still haven't found a solution the following worked for me:

Define the following function

```
def enable_plotly_in_cell():
  import IPython
  from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''<script 
  src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>'''))
  init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
```

Then just place it here

```
(...)
enable_plotly_in_cell()
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=lt)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: For quality and long term value, consider highlighting the most relevant portions of your solution with an explanation. Most upvotes are from future visitors who learn from it to apply to their own coding issues.